# Left clicking on list element and hidding the remains ones

Tags: javascript, html, list

I have a list that is hidden. When you search the list it will show(like an search engine) just the elements that you searched for. I want that when I left-click on some element from the list the remain ones will hide.

I tried something like this, it's the only code that I have left in my comments.

```
Function hideme(){
var ul, li, i;

    ul = document.getElementById("listsearch");
    li = ul.getElementsByTagName("li");

  for (i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
    //li[i].style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("listsearch").children[i+1].style.display ="none";
}
```

It's not good at all and I really don't know what to do now. I tried lots of variants, but it has to count the list tags and hide the ones that are not clicked.

```
<input type="text" id="cautaechipamente" onkeyup="searchech()" placeholder="Search for..." name="search">
          <ul id="listsearch" class="list-group">
            <li><a href="javascript:hidelist()" name="#">Element 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="javascript:hidelist()" name="#">Element 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="javascript:hidelist()" name="#">Text 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="javascript:hidelist()" name="#">Text 2</a></li>
        </ul>
```

Here is the code for hiding the list:

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#listsearch li").hide();
  });
```

And I'm using this function to search through elements:

```
function searchech() {
  var input, filter, ul, li, a, i;
  input = document.getElementById('cautaechipamente');
  filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
  ul = document.getElementById("listsearch");
  li = ul.getElementsByTagName('li');

  if(input.value.length == 0){
      ul.style.display = "none";
      return;
  }else{
      ul.style.display = "block";
  }
  // Cauta prin toate itemele, ascunde ce nu este ca in input search
  for (i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
      a = li[i].getElementsByTagName("a")[0];
      if (a.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
          li[i].style.display = "block";
      } else {
          li[i].style.display = "none";
      }
  }
    }
```

I expect that when you click on 'Element 1', 'Element 2' and 'Text 2' are going to hide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you can do is set an event `onClick` for your `li a` elements like:

```
HTML

<input type="text" id="cautaechipamente" onkeyup="searchech()" placeholder="Search for..." name="search"> 
<button id="resetBtn">reset</button>
          <ul id="listsearch" class="list-group">
            <li><a href="#" name="#">Element 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" name="#">Element 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" name="#">Text 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" name="#">Text 2</a></li>
        </ul>



JS

$('li').click(function() {
    $('li').not(this).hide();
    $(this).find('li').toggle();
});

$('#resetBtn').click(function(){
        $('li').show();
    $(this).find('li').toggle();
});
```

In this case I created a button that reset the properties.

Comment: It's ok, but if you want to delete the input and search for something else you will only get the last result; To fix this you have to refresh the page. How can I reset the input after I delete what's in the search box.

I tried with: document.getElementById('myform').reset(); but I have somehow to call this after the search box in empty.

Comment: Thank you @corrado4eyes. I found out how to that a bit after I wrote you. I can't give you an up-vote, but i'm going to make 15 votes to upvote your answer. It helped me a lot, i'm going to read more about jQuerty it's pretty useful.

Comment: Yeah, don't worry, the important is that you solved your problem